# CSS - odd and even does not work

Tags: html, css

I want to use the pseudo selectors odd end even. But if sequence of element is divided by another element, e.g. a heading the order of odd and even is broken. How can I continue the initial order?

[JS FIDLLE](https://jsfiddle.net/stoaurkd/)

HTML

```
<div class="fig">
     <figcaption>t</figcaption>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
  <div>headline</div>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
    <figcaption></figcaption>    
    <figcaption></figcaption>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.fig figcaption:nth-child(even) {
 background:green;
}

.fig figcaption:nth-child(odd) {
  background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Have you even read what `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` do? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, **regardless of type**, of its parent.

Comment: Forget your CSS, 1) why do you have a `div class=fig` instead of a `figure`? 2) why do you have a `div` for a "headline"? 3) what is a "headline" doing in the middle of a series of `figcaption`s? 4) why do you have so many `figcaption`s in the same parent in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply use

```
figcaption:nth-of-type(odd)
figcaption:nth-of-type(even)
```

***[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stoaurkd/7/)***

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-child (odd)` doesn't check no of `figcaption` and calculate odd and even based on it. It checks based on your Parent element `div`

[nth-child DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/stoaurkd/4/)

`:nth-of-type(odd)` it check the no of `figcaption` and calculate odd and even based on them.

[nth-of-type DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/stoaurkd/9/)

Answer (score -3):

Wrapping each figure sets in another div will work as you expect

```
<div class="fig">
    <div>
        <figcaption>t</figcaption>
        <figcaption></figcaption>
    </div>
    <div>headline</div>  
    <div>
        <figcaption></figcaption>
        <figcaption></figcaption>
        <figcaption></figcaption>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is true, if the OP is able to modify the HTML then they really should be rewriting the whole thing. Except it's not clear what the markup is supposed to represent, so it's pretty much impossible to suggest how the markup *should* be written instead.